# How to write an @overrides allennlp predictor.load_line?

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

AllenNLP has a predictor function that takes in a JSON file then output a JSON file. From the documentation one can @overrides predictor.load_line and write in a function to take in, say, a text file.

How would you write this function? And how to implement the function (ie import it as a module)?

AllenNLP load_line API: https://allenai.github.io/allennlp-docs/api/allennlp.predictors.html?highlight=sentencetaggerpredictor#allennlp.predictors.predictor.Predictor

I am following the tutorial here:
https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/tutorials/tagger/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can install the AllenNLP framework locally on your drive and then update the code manually there. Resume normal functionality after that with the changes reloaded.

Or, you could [dynamically update the class method](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2013/07/05/run-time-method-patching-python/). This is like patching the third-party code and ensuring the updates are distributed down the chain. [Another article here](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2016/how-to-make-a-python-method).

Comment: That's a very general answer. I was looking for something with a decorator @overrides and the code that read a text file into the function.

Comment: @bottledatthesource your question is also very general and doesn't show much effort. With such questions it's very likely to get such answers.